# Argument treatment at command line in C

Tags: c, operating-system, command-line-arguments

The question asked to me is that even if we supplied integer/float arguments at the command prompt they are still treated as strings or not in C language. I am not sure about that can any help just little bit. Is this true or not in C language and why? And what about others like Java or python ?

Comment: yes it is, and you may used atoi to convet to int, and so on

Comment: So if your program takes the following arguments `float, int, string, float` how would you propose to pass them to your program in a standard and generic way across all programming languages? You could make them structures but would end up having more issues than it is worth. Passing them in as strings is the most generic and unassuming way.

Answer (score 2):

It is true, independent of the language, that the command line arguments to programs on Unix are strings.  If the program chooses to interpret them as numbers, that is fine, but it is because the program (or programmer) chose to do so.  Similarly, the runtime support for a language might alter the arguments passed by the o/s into integer or float types, but the o/s passes strings to that runtime (I know of no language that does this, but I don't claim to know all languages).

To see this, note that the ways to execute a program are the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html) family of functions, and each of those takes a string which is the name of the program to be executed, and an array of strings which are the arguments to be passed to the program.  Functions such as [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) and [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) are built atop the `exec*()` family of functions — they also use [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html), of course.  Even the [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) function takes an array of pointers to strings for the arguments of the spawned program.

Answer (score 1):

It's not unlike mailing a letter without an envelope. We all agree to use the common enclosure known as an envelope. Operating systems pass parameters to programs using the common item known as a string of characters. It's beyond the scope of the operating system to understand what the program wants to do with the parameters.

There are some exceptions, one which comes to mind is the passing of parameters to a Linux Kernel Module. These can be passed as items other than strings.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is an issue of creating an interface between the operating system and the program. *any* program. Remember that programs are not always written in C, And you don't even know whether there are things like `float` or `int` in the language.

You want to be able to pass several arguments (with natural delimiters), which may easily encode arbitrary information. In C, strings can be of arbitrary length, and the only constraint on them is that a zero byte in them signifies the end of the string. this is a highly flexible and natural way to pass arbitrary information to the program.

So you can never supply an arbitrary integer/float arguments directly to a program; The operating system (Unix / Linux / Windows / etc.) won't let you. You don't have any tool that gives you that interface, in the same way that you can't pass a mouse-click as an argument. All you supply is a sequence of characters.

Since Unix and C were designed together, it is also part of the C programming language, and from there it worked its way to C++, Java, Python and most other modern programming languages, and the same way into Linux, Windows and most other operating systems.